# Enable a Disabled Submit Button when both a Select field and Input field each have Values?

Tags: jquery, form-submit, disabled-control, submit-button

I love this site, and have been able to learn so much from you all. However, here is a problem I cannot find the answer to:

I have a mini-form with a Select dropdown and an Input field (both required) with a disabled Submit button. My client needs the submit button to be disabled/grayed out until both of these fields are filled, but I cannot get the action to work.

The code I provided only works with the Input so far. I tried to incorporate "**($('#selectBox').on('change', function() {**" within the initial function to signal to the Select field, but it breaks everything and I don't know where to go with it.

Rather than having the fields work independently (as I appear to have been doing), I think each field needs to bounce/read off each other within the JQuery code to decipher that each field has a valid value. But I am struggling to find the connection (I am still fairly new to JS/JQ - please pardon my ignorance considering this assumption, if wrong).

I searched everywhere for a solution, but I have not had any luck finding the answer. Please let me know if I missed a link or previous question which can help me, and thank you for any insights!

https://jsfiddle.net/jdraeger/2w68qs0y/2/

```js
$(function() {
      $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
          $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
          $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
        }
      });
   })
```

```html
<body>
  <div id='frame'>
    <div class='search'>
      <form method='post'>
        <select id="selectBox" class="selectBox" required>
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='searchQuery' id='searchInput' required/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two fields and two events...

You can write one "handler" for this. Simply use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which allows to bind many events (`keyup` and `change` here). Then, in the comparison, check both value. If one **or** the other is empty, disable the button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searchInput, #selectBox').on('keyup change',function() {
    if ($('#searchInput').val() == '' || $('#selectBox').val() == '') {
      $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='frame'>
    <div class='search'>
      <form method='post'>
        <select id="selectBox" class="selectBox" required>
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='searchQuery' id='searchInput' required/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This could even be writen shorter, by placing the condition directly in the true/false second argument of `.prop()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searchInput, #selectBox').on('keyup change',function() {
    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', ($('#searchInput').val() == '' || $('#selectBox').val() == ''));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='frame'>
    <div class='search'>
      <form method='post'>
        <select id="selectBox" class="selectBox" required>
          <option value="">--Select--</option>
          <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
          <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='searchQuery' id='searchInput' required/>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' class='enableOnInput' disabled='disabled' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Both versions worked perfectly :) I appreciate the shorter version for cleaner coding, although I find the longer one to be easier to read syntax-wise for understanding the flow (again, I'm still learning this language). Again, thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating a new function which will make enable your submit button and will be called whenever either text input field changes or select field changes

```
$('#selectBox','#searchInput').on('change', function() {
 enablingFunction();
 });

function enablingFunction(){
  if($('#selectBox').val() != "" && $('#searchInput').val() != ""){
    $('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", false);
   }
}
```